# Is there a way to use querySelector to get an open shadow dom

Tags: javascript, shadow-dom, html5-template

Suppose I created and inserted an element like this

```
<template id="react-web-component">
  <span>template stuff</span
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</template>
<script>
  (function (window, document) {
    const doc = (document._currentScript || document.currentScript).ownerDocument;
    const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      attachedCallback: {
        value: function () {
          const template = doc.querySelector('template#react-web-component').content;
          const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
          shadowRoot.appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));
        },
      },
    });
    document.registerElement('react-web-component', { prototype: proto });
  })(window, document);
</script>
<react-web-component></react-web-component>
```

Now I wanna use a `querySelector` to access the *open* shadow dom of my element. Like this:

```
document.querySelector('react-web-component::shadow')
```

But this does not work. Is there any other way?

**edit** in response to @Supersharp 's answer

> Sorry, I wasn't making myself clear. I am using webpack's `style-loader` that only accepts a CSS selector that it uses with `document.querySelector`, so what I am asking is for a CSS selector I can use this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an editor draft for it (hence it does not exist yet), if i understood you right.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#selectors

So answer is "no", you can't do it.

Answer (score 9):

Get it by the `shadowRoot` property of the Shadow host:

```
document.querySelector('react-web-component').shadowRoot
```

**Update**

There used to be this kind of CSS selector, but now it is deprecated.

Maybe you could try to use normal DOM instead of Shadow DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't making myself clear. I am using webpack's `style-loader` that only accepts a CSS selector that it uses with `document.querySelector`, so what I am asking is for a CSS selector I can use this way.

Comment: There's no selector for that. Maybe you should consider not using shadow dom.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an improved version of querySelector which iterates only elements without children which more likely could have shadowRoot:

```
const querySelector = function (selector, root = document) {
    const nodes = [...root.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    const shadowNodes = [...root.querySelectorAll(':empty')].filter(node => node.shadowRoot);

    shadowNodes.map(shNode => {
        nodes.push(...querySelector(selector, shNode.shadowRoot));
    })

    return nodes;
}
```

Usage example:

```
querySelector('#input');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the problem:

```
const querySelectorAll = (node,selector) => {
    const nodes = [...node.querySelectorAll(selector)],
        nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(node, Node.ELEMENT_NODE);
    let currentNode;
    while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
        if(currentNode.shadowRoot) {
            nodes.push(...querySelectorAll(currentNode.shadowRoot,selector));
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```